# python small crosswords for beginners

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
my_str="ellezagchickenbndodetballigatoraaaolmeznacattleeblrctacfenarcesssadlritfhftrarrssos aoiarefaareppohssarghcerumrheirmmwildfcumeboimltaairfovindalbiglalobehoeasiaxuesabldinbbccrhhrtylrlahsifdlogkrctlaiareogoldfinchefnnddmneepoletnarntadodinosauroxofoeclictnahpelepalgaierhohcaorkcocyatrmoacrflamingoerefafloechateehchdracaribou"
def create_2d_list(N):
    output_list=[]
    counter=0
    for row in range(0,N):
        temp=[]
        for col in range(0,N):
            temp.append(my_str[counter])#you can add a charcter instead of counter
            counter=counter+1
        output_list.append(temp[:])
    return output_list

N=18

x=create_2d_list(N)

for row in range(0,N):
    total=0
    s="|"
    for col in range(0,N):
        my_str="{0:2} ".format(x[row][col])
        s=s+my_str+"|"
    print "-"*(N*4+1)
    print s,
    print " "

the_valid_words=open("E:/asd/words.txt","r").readlines()


def looking_word_left_to_right(the_list):
    for any_words in the_valid_words:
        for every in x[0]:
            the_first_index=x[0].index(every)
            for every in range(the_first_index,(the_first_index)+7):
                c=str(every)
                the_join=" ".join(c)
                if the_join==the_valid_words:
                    word.upper().replace(every,x[0].upper(every))
                return x[0]

print looking_word_left_to_right(x)
```

every time i run the program, the looking_word_left_to_right doesn't print anything

P.S its similar to small crossword for beginners, Capitalizing the letters that make a word and removing every other letter without changing places, if someone could give like thoughts on how to proceed that would be great. i have certain valid words to look for.

and i'm a newbie so go easy on me :)
appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you ever actually print looking_word_left_to_right?  I dont' see it.

Comment: no i didnt, but i added it but it print the first row as a list, without capitalizing anything

Comment: Please fix your indentation of your nested for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be a number of problems.

- Why are you operating on `x` when you also pass it in as `the_list"` Just use `the_list`.
- You're only looking at the first line of `x` and never moving beyond that.
- It looks like you're putting a space between every character *before* you compare. If c = "abcdefg" then `" ".join(c)` will give you `"a b c d e f g"`. If your `the_valid_words` doesn't have spaces in it, then `if the_join==the_valid_words` will always evaluate to false.
- You're comparing to `the_valid_words,` which is your entire list. You should probably be comparing to *EACH* valid word using `any_word`... which you aren't using anywhere else.
- You may also be running into a problem with iterating over `x`, while you're changing it (it will sometimes invalidate the iterator... but sometimes not). I.e. if you're iterating through `x` and then you change `x` before you're done iterating, then Python might not know where the iterator belongs in the new version of `x`. Since `the_list` is the same as `x` anyway, it might be better to do `for every in the_list:` and then change `x` to your heart's content.

It looks like you may not quite understand how for loops work in Python. Take a look at those, and that may help some.